# How to concatenate a tensor to a keras layer along batch (without specifying batch size)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to concatenate the output from an embedding layer with a custom tensor (`myarr` / `myconst`). I can specify everything with a fixed batch size like follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 100
myarr = np.ones((10, 5))
myconst = tf.constant(np.tile(myarr, (BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1)))

# Model definition
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10, 5)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x, myconst])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

However, if I don't specify batch size and tile my array, i.e. just the following...

```py
myarr = np.ones((10, 5))
myconst = tf.constant(myarr)

# Model definition
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10, 5)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x, myconst])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

... I get an error specifying that shapes `[(None, 10, 5), (10, 5)]` can't be concatenated. Is there a way to add this `None` / batch_size axis to avoid tiling?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to concatenate to a 3D tensor of shape `(batch, 10, 5)` a constant of shape `(10, 5)` along the batch dimensionality. To do this your constant must be 3D. So you have to reshape it in `(1, 10, 5)` and repeat it along the `axis=0` in order to match the shape `(batch, 10, 5)` and operate a concatenation.

We do this inside a `Lambda` layer:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (100,10))
Y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,20,5))

myarr = np.ones((1, 10, 5)).astype('float32')
myconst = tf.convert_to_tensor(myarr)

def repeat_const(tensor, myconst):
    shapes = tf.shape(tensor)
    return tf.repeat(myconst, shapes[0], axis=0)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10, 5)(inputs)
xx = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: repeat_const(x, myconst))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x, xx])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=3)
```